# C code compilation

Tags: c, windows, compilation

i want to compile a 'c' code and create an executable from my application. as of now i do it by specifying the path of my compilation .exe (c++) present in the bin folder of my Dev-Cpp folder.

it works fine but i need to pack the compiler along with the application so i wanted to know what files and folders are needed so that i can compile it directly from the application.

what are the files needed exactly i.e. headers,the compilation application, libs and what else...

any help?

Comment: a) why don't you compile it locally? b) the obvious missing info: what's your compiler and OS?

Comment: +1 @Karoly.  And to the OP - even if you do want to ship source code, why do you need to ship the compiler along with it?

Comment: There's no need to ship a compiler. If someone else is not able to get the compiler on their own, they're not going to be able to use the one you include.

Comment: @CarlNorum / Karoly: People embed scripting languages into their programs all the time.  It's not unreasonable to want to make something that has the behavior of a compiler (outputting executables) without writing the whole thing from scratch.  In fact the first C++ compiler actually built C code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront

Comment: @HostileFork, that's true, but doesn't sound like what the OP's trying to do at all.

Comment: @CarlNorum It's perhaps *possible* the question is simply *"how do I compile and distribute my code to another machine"*. But I don't see any good reason to *assume* the intent isn't *"i want to compile a [application-generated] 'c' code and create an executable from [inside of] my application"*. Dev-C++ is turnkey for producing EXEs...and they're seeking out paths...this sounds to me like a primitively-phrased question about generative programming.  (I just don't like it when people assume someone is an idiot and downvotes them for interesting questions because phrasing isn't perfect.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to create and distribute a project which is able to build upon an existing compiler for its functionality, there are packages you can find which are just the compiler portion without the IDE.  Minimalist GNU for Windows is such a package:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW

*(In fact, when the people who put together Dev-C++ wrote their integrated development environment, they get the actual compilation functionality from MinGW...which they bundled into their package for good measure.  So if you were going to write an IDE of your own, you would start from the MinGW distribution...not by trying to hand-pick files out of Dev-C++.)*

One issue to be sensitive to is licensing.  While there are not generally any legal issues out of the box regarding distributing executables built with a system like MinGW, when you go as far as to include the compiler in your own "product", it might be tricky.  Dev-C++ is under the same license as MinGW (GPL) but I'd imagine there'd be issues if it were not.

If you only need a subset of the full functionality (let's say you only compile C and not C++) there will be a lot of header files and such that you could cut out.  But you have to trade off the difficulty of maintaining this sort of optimization vs. just having your program ask users to install MinGW and then tell your program where they installed it.  It might take up more space and lead installation to be a two-step process...but frees you from a large number of concerns.

So that's what I would suggest: Have a setting in your program (much like Dev-C++ does) which lets people specify where the MinGW binaries are installed on their system.  But let them install it independently.